# 501 error when visiting mobile site with mitmproxy

Tags: http-error, charles-proxy, mitmproxy

When visiting a mobile site with mitmproxy, a `501 not implemented` page appears. but it's normal for me to access with [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Charles is similar to mitmproxy, a commonly used packet capturing tool under Mac

Comment: Is the 501 response generated by mitmproxy or the server (see the mitmproxy data).

Comment: the server maybe.